# Insert note if subsection does not end on page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, conditionals

Say we are reading a document and just reached the very end of page 2. We are a currently in a random subsection at the end of page 2.

At that position, I would like to have a note which reads like:

> *... continued on page 3*

I suppose I can easily create the text itself, but neither the conditional part or "look-ahead to determine the next page number"-part  around it.

```
\newcommand{\noteForContinuation}{%
\vspace{1ex}\par\singlespacing\raggedleft%
\begin{minipage}{0.9\columnwidth}%
\emph\small(\ldots continue on page 4)%
\end{minipage}\par\vspace{0ex}\onehalfspacing}
```

Is there a way to insert this note at the end of a page, if the condition is met that the content for the current **subsection** continues on the next page?

## Mock-up of goal

[image]

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper,
]
{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
blindtext
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}

\listfiles
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\blinddocument
%\blindtext[5]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can get the current page using `\thepage` which gives the value of the page counter. To get the next page do `\addtocounter{page}{1}\thepage\addtocounter{page}{-1}` which adds one to get the next page number, gives you the value and then removes the extra 1 you added.